# CreateCriteria - Use logical OR in hasMany association

Tags: grails, grails-orm, has-many, createcriteria

I want to get instances who contain in their lists (firstsList or SecondsList) a specific user.
In my solution, the create criteria takes into account only the first list of users.
It seems to be a bad usage of the logical OR

**Domain**

```
class ClassA {
    static hasMany =  [firstsList:User,SecondsList:User]
}
```

**Service**

```
def idList =  ClassA.createCriteria().list () {

projections { distinct ( "id" )
    property("name")
    property("id")
}

or {                 
   firstsList{eq("login", 'John')}             
   SecondsList{eq("login", 'John')}                                 
 }

order("name","desc")

}

return idList
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind this is hibernate by default uses `inner join`. But in your case you need `left join`. For that you can use `createAlias` of `createCriteria`.

```
    def idList = ClassA.createCriteria().list() {
        projections { 
            distinct("id")
            property("name")               
        }

        createAlias("firstsList", "fl", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
        createAlias("SecondsList", "sl", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
        or {                 
            eq("fl.login", "John")             
            eq("sl.login", "John")                                
        }

        order("name", "desc")
    }
```